# How to view installed Python packages

Tags: python, package

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and want to use the dropbox package. My plan was to download the package using the command prompt and then copy/paste the package into Sublime's installed packages folder.

At the command prompt I typed this code to install dropbox:

```
C:\Python\Scripts\pip install dropbox
```

The output contained a lot of "stuff" but towards the end is:

```
Successfully installed certifi-2019.11.28 chardet-3.0.4 dropbox-9.4.0 idna-2.8 requests-2.22.0 urllib3-1.25.7
```

So it appears to have installed successfully but I can't see any of the mentioned packages in the C:\Python\Lib folder. Is this not where the packages are kept?

Comment: `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages`, but more simply, run `pip list` or `pip freeze`

Comment: Do you want to use this as part of a Sublime Text package? If not, then this question is not Sublime related because all Sublime does to run Python programs is tell the OS to execute `python` (i.e. the fact that you're using Sublime to edit Python files doesn't impact where the Python tools put their own files). Also, note that the `Installed Packages` folder is for Sublime Text packages (i.e. plugins, syntaxes, etc) not Python packages.

Answer (score 3):

`pip list` will show you installed packages in your environment.

Sublime is a text editor, not an IDE, and therefore does have this feature built in. I'm unaware of extensions that offer similar functionality. Your interpreter will determine where to check for packages when the script is ran, not Sublime.

From your command-line prompt:

```
>> pip3 install dropbox
>> pip3 list # alternatively, pip3 show dropbox
...
dropbox                  9.4.0
...
>> python3 path/to/my/dropbox/using/script.py
```

`pip3 show <package_name>` will list information about the package including where it is located.

Answer (score 1):

Installed packages are kept in this directory: `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages`

There is a pip command called `list`. Use this command to see all packages you have installed. There are also some options to use along with this command. See the "[`pip list`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/) documentation for more information.

If the package has been installed elsewhere, you can find the installation location using the `show your_package` command. This command will show all information about the installed package.

**Example:**

```
pip show dropbox
```

**Output:**

```
Name: dropbox
Version: 9.4.0
Summary: Official Dropbox API Client
Home-page: http://www.dropbox.com/developers
Author: Dropbox
Author-email: dev-platform@dropbox.com
License: MIT License
Location: c:\users\jean extreme\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires: six, requests
Required-by:
```

---

Try importing dropbox to find out if it works:

```
import dropbox
print("It works :)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pip list` or `pip list > requirements.txt` and process the file manualy to generate a requirements file to no virtual enviroments.